# Intellij IDEA 12: How to get PEP8 on the fly

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, pep8

It seems this is already supported in [PyCharm 2.7](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2013/02/long-awaited-pep-8-checks-on-the-fly-improved-doctest-support-and-more-in-pycharm-2-7/)

How can I get that for my IntelliJ IDEA 12? Currently for each file I do this

[image]

**UPDATE**
As mentioned by @CrazyCoder, after updating to IDEA 12.1, I can see PEP8 recommendations while I type

[image]

Comment: Maybe you need to install the Python plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Available in [IDEA 12.1](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12.1+EAP) with the new Python plug-in (2.10.1):

[image: pep8]

[image: plug-in]

Comment: I can not find the plugin anymore.

Comment: This works, but IntelliJ's default reformatting is not 100% compatible with PEP8. Is there are any way to solve this?